# Find user desktop path using either javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, location, desktop

how to find user desktop location using jquery or javascript?
in my project i have to create and save prn file to user desktop location,file creation is done by below php script.

```
<?php
$handle = fopen("file1.prn", "w");
fwrite($handle, "prn format");
fclose($handle);
readfile('file1.prn');
exit;
?>
```

i already tried with php script to save in user desktop, but no proper solution i found.
is this possible in javascript or jquery?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: You want to save files from your Webserver to a User Desktop while visiting your Site?

Comment: Change your browser setting for download any file to desktop.

Comment: This portal is global,using by various vendors through out world,its not possible to ask every vendor to change their settings in browser.directly it has to go their desktop.

Comment: yes @Webice,when user visit my site,file has to save into their local system(desktop)..any idea?

Comment: It can't be possible. Than it were to easy to spread viruses !

Comment: omg :-( my bad luck :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not an expert, but Javascript same-origin policy make this impossible without a confirmation action by user.

Try something like :

```
<input type="file" id="fileinput" />
```

Then :

```
function readSingleFile(evt) {
                var f = evt.target.files[0];
                if (f) {  }

              }
document.getElementById('fileinput').addEventListener('change', readSingleFile, false);
```

Once f is opened, you just have to write in it =)

Comment: i tried the above one,couldn't make it work `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of undefined `,moreover i am not letting user to upload file,file has to create and save into their local system,could you please give me more suggestion.